# Pass bool param from VSTS to Powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

If I need to pass a boolean value from VSTS to powershell script to do the deployment in CD. I get the below error though:

> Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.

I pass the param from VSTS as inline script `-ClientCertificateEnabled "$(ClientCertificateEnabled)"`

And replcae values in `template.json` using `replacetoken.ps1` via `parameters.local.jason`.

**parameters.local.jason**

```
"clientCertEnabled": {
      "value": "{{clientCertificateEnabled}}"
    },
```

**replacetoken.ps1**

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [bool]
    $ClientCertificateEnabled

$depParametersFile = $depParametersFile.Replace('{{clientCertificateEnabled}}', $ClientCertificateEnabled)
```

**deploy.ps1**

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [bool]
  $ClientCertificateEnabled
```

**template.json**

```
"clientCertEnabled": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": true,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Indicates if client certificate is required on web applications on Azure."
      }
    }

 "clientCertEnabled": "[parameters('clientCertEnabled')]"
```

Comment: I don't know about VSTS, but the error seems pretty simple. Your using the value `"0"` or `"1"` which is considered a string while `0 1 $true $false` are actual boolean values in Powershell (Notice the lack of quotations). Please include your code so we can determine where the error occurs.

Comment: And the code behind it all looks like what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to address the issue with below change and reverted back Boolean type back to string in all the  ps1 files.

Changed `parameters.local.json` as below (just removed double quote)

```
"clientCertEnabled": {
      "value": {{clientCertificateEnabled}}
    },
```

So with the above change after executing `replacetoken.ps1` `parameters.local.json` will look like below

```
"clientCertEnabled": {
      "value": true
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are writing a distributed task, VSTS/AzureDevOps will pass all the parameters as string.  You need to declare your ps1 param block to accept strings and internally convert them.

I haven't used the PowerShell task to invoke scripts (only inline script) so I don't know how it passes parameters.  It would be safe to assume it does the same passing of strings.

```
param
(
    [string]$OverwriteReadOnlyFiles = "false"
)
```

I wrote a Convert-ToBoolean function to handle the conversion and call it.

```
[bool]$shouldOverwriteReadOnlyFiles = Convert-ToBoolean $OverwriteReadOnlyFiles
```

The function is defined as:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
    Converts a value into a boolean
.DESCRIPTION 
    Takes an input string and converts it into a [bool]
.INPUTS
    No pipeline input.
.OUTPUTS
    True if the string represents true
    False if the string represents false
    Default if the string could not be parsed
.PARAMETER StringValue
    Optional.  The string to be parsed.
.PARAMETER Default
    Optional.  The value to return if the StringValue could not be parsed.
    Defaults to false if not provided.
.NOTES
.LINK
#>
function Convert-ToBoolean
(
    [string]$StringValue = "",
    [bool]$Default = $false
)
{
    [bool]$result = $Default

    switch -exact ($StringValue)
    {
         "1"     { $result = $true;  break; }
         "-1"    { $result = $true;  break; }
         "true"  { $result = $true;  break; }
         "yes"   { $result = $true;  break; }
         "y"     { $result = $true;  break; }
         "0"     { $result = $false; break; }
         "false" { $result = $false; break; }
         "no"    { $result = $false; break; }
         "n"     { $result = $false; break; }
    }

    Write-Output $result
}
```

Comment: I've always used .net Boolean TryParse. Does that not cover your normal use cases?

Comment: No.  TryParse does not recognise the strings 1 and 0 as true and false values.  It only wants to convert the string values true and false into boolean.